How can I formally verify the correctness of my WaitGroup implementation in C++?
Description
I've implemented a WaitGroup in C++ assuming that:

user must ensure that the counter value does not drop below zero.
WaitGroup can be reused.

Below is my code:
class WaitGroup {
 public:
  void Add(size_t count) {
    lock_guard<mutex> lock(mutex_);
    count_ += count;
  }

  void Done() {
    lock_guard<mutex> lock(mutex_);
    if (--count_ == 0) {
      cv_.notify_all();
    }
  }

  void Wait() {
    unique_lock<mutex> lock(mutex_);
    cv_.wait(lock, [this] { return count_ == 0; });
  }

 private:
  size_t count_{0};
  mutex mutex_;
  condition_variable cv_;
};

Question
How can I formally verify the correctness of my WaitGroup implementation?
What is a general way to prove such things?

You can write and run tests, but formal proof of correctness I doubt is going to be possible.

The first step would be to decide what you are actually trying to prove.  You need to formally specify the intended semantics of the object and its methods.

Since count_ is size_t, which is unsigned, it is impossible for it to drop below zero...

This blog I read today specifically says that proven correctness is just impossible.

@prapin: That's not what it says.  It says that you can't prove it through testing and measuring code coverage, which is true.  But you can, in many cases, prove it by formal logical analysis.  In fact that's exactly what the author says in item 6 of the FAQ.

Side note: I think you already have a bug. What happens if Done is called before anything else? Is that case handled correctly? If Done is called only after a corresponding Add, how do you prove that? And, how does the code check for this? Just saying that no users of the class will ever call Done in bad circumstances probably isn't enough for a proof. Even if you could prove correctness of the class, how do we prove other code uses it safely?

@CraigEstey, user must ensure that Done() is not called more times than Add(size_t) at any particular moment.

That's what I was hinting at, but the class should check/enforce this. Done checks for going negative [and aborts]. Add could check some [arbitrary/realistic] upper bound (e.g. 20) and abort if going higher. It's a lot easier to do these checks than to troubleshoot a missed notify (i.e. threads hanging). Also, the class could add a timeout on such locking/waiting (possibly based on a compile time debug flag).

To formally verify the correctness of your class, you would need to draw all possible paths your logic could take and prove mathematically that it indeed does what it's supposed to. So, let's say that practically that's not possible (not in a fast and automated way).
But I can tell you how to increase the chances of your implementation being bug-free. The first step would be to define the requirements. Your

user must ensure that the counter value does not drop below zero

statement is already flawed, because here count_ is a private field, an implementation detail, and you should not rely on it. Better requirements would be:

User shall have the possibility to Add any number of tasks
User shall have the possibility to Wait (blocking) for all the current tasks to finish (i.e. number of active tasks is 0)
User shall have the possibility to mark a single task as Done
WaitGroup shall be thread-safe
WaitGroup shall be reusable

And then you design tests to cover the requirements. The first obvious scenario that comes to mind is:

asynchronously add 10 tasks to the queue, then asynchronously mark all of them as DONE, then Wait

TEST(xxx, yyy) {
    WaitGroup sut;
    std::vector<std::future<void>> tasks;
    constexpr int NUM_TASKS = 10;
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_TASKS; i++) {
        tasks.push_back(std::async(std::launch::async, [&]() {
            sut.Add(1);
        }));
    }
    tasks.clear();  // join all threads to have all tasks added
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_TASKS; i++) {
        tasks.push_back(std::async(std::launch::async, [&]() {
            sut.Done();
        }));
    }
    sut.Wait();  // what if never returns? problem?
    // then run the above logic once again, to test for "reusable" requirement
}

In this test you can immediately spot a couple of issues, e.g.:

what if sut.Wait() never returns, either because of the bug, or because of misuse? Maybe you should add a int timeout argument and throw an exception when wait_for returns false?
what if Done is called more times than Add(1)? Currently you have unsigned int underflow, maybe you should throw an exception, or print a warning and make it no-op?
also check for scenario when user calls Add(x) with x > 1
[optimization] is std::mutex really needed, maybe you can achieve the same with std::atomic_int?

So you will possibly change a bit your interfaces, your implementation, and write some more tests to cover different corner-cases. Then you could run your suite with the tool that can detect different memory and threading bugs, like valgrind, and you will have a good chance of deploying good quality code.

About using atomic to avoid locks in Add and Done:
At the end of this post explanation why we can miss notify if we make shared variable atomic (assuming that shared variable is used in condvar as a condition)
